# React: Style css valid does not allow focus

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using React for my app. I am following [one tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8YshrNwN8I) from youtube. I want convert that html and css into react css. Until css focus it works fine and it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSTDL.png) and when I click the input area the label goes up-to border. As soon as I implement `valid`, Then the valid does not allow the focus and it stuck up there [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvOz2.png). I don't know does React allow css valid or not.

**This is my Input component**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import './new.css'


const Text = () => {

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" className="inputField" />
        <label htmlFor="name" className="labels">First name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Text;
```

**This is the css**

```
.main{
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.inputField{
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 13px;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  font-size:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  }

  .inputField:focus{
  border: 2px solid royalblue;
  }
.labels{
  color: #8d8d8d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.inputField:valid + .labels{ //This valid does not allow focus
  top: -11px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
} 

 .inputField:focus + .labels {
  top: -11px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: royalblue;
  transition: 300ms;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the state of `:valid` is always valid for the input text so you need to specify that it's focused and valid. You could add "required" to it, but you may want to handle the focus depending if the validation is met.

See the code below and click the **"Run code snippet"** button.

```js
// main.js

(() => {

  const TextAlwaysValid = () => (<div className="always-valid"><div className="input-group"><input autoComplete="off" type="text" id="firstname" className="inputField" /><label htmlFor="name" className="labels">Always Valid</label></div></div>);
  
    const TextAlwaysValidRequired = () => (<div className="always-valid"><div className="input-group"><input autoComplete="off" required type="text" id="firstname" className="inputField" /><label htmlFor="name" className="labels">Has Required</label></div></div>);
  
  const TextValidWorking = () => (<div className="main"><div className="input-group"><input autoComplete="off" type="text" id="firstname" className="inputField" /><label htmlFor="name" className="labels">Valid + Focus</label></div></div>);
  
  const App = () => (<div><TextAlwaysValid /><br /><TextAlwaysValidRequired /><br /><TextValidWorking /></div>);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
  
  
})();
```

```css
/* style.css */
.main, .always-valid {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.inputField{
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 13px;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  font-size:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.inputField:focus{
  border: 2px solid royalblue;
}

.labels{
  color: #8d8d8d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.inputField:focus + .labels {
  top: -11px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: royalblue;
  transition: 300ms;
}

/* This Works */
.main .inputField:focus+:valid + .labels {
  top: -11px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
}

/* Original Code Will Not Work Because Always Valid */
.always-valid .inputField:valid + .labels {
  top: -11px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- babel is required in order to parse JSX -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```